# passing state with link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly new to react and would like to pass an argument through a link. I know I can do this by using the State and so I did.

```
<td>
   <Link to={{pathname:"user/"+id, state:{user_url:item.url} }} >{item.name}</Link>
</td>
```

This will redirect to my user_detail component,

```
export default class User_Details extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error : null,
            isloading: true,
            user_detail : null,
            user_url : null

        };
        if (this.props.location.state){
            this.state.user_url =this.props.location.state.user_url
        }
    }
```

A user can get on this user_detail component via a redirect link or just via a url, if it get there via the redirect link then I don't have to get the user_url from the because it is saved in the state. However if a user uses a link that doesn't have a state then I first have to get the link.

This works however I keep getting a warning error if I use a redirect link:

> index.js:1446 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak
>   in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous
>   tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
>       in User (created by Context.Consumer)

How would I be able to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate state like this I would suggest you to use setState in `componentDidMount` like this

```
    componentDidMount() {
      if (this.props.location.state){
               this.setState({
                 user_url: this.props.location.state.user_url
               });
      }
   }
```

Comment: thx for the feedback, I didn't know about the componentDidMount functions and update in react, I did this in the render funcion which is ofc wrong and keeps rendering.

Answer (score 0):

like user  Rishabh Rawat said I had to use the componentDidMount function , here I made the async call, but instead of setting the state with the setstate function if the argument of the user_link was passed on I did this.state.user_link = this.prop.location.state.user_link. Not the SetState because this is sometimes delayed wich caused some crashes.

Comment: You should never mutate state directly like this, setState is an async function if there are some crashes maybe you should provide some checks for your app which are causing the crashes